# Is it a different procedure for a spay during heat than one not during?

Tags: dogs, neutering

We're considering having our small Cairn spayed. However, as she's in heat, the vet added an extra charge which is some multiple of the spaying itself. The charge is just "spay in heat".

What's different between a spay during heat and outside of heat? We're going to wait but I am curious how the procedure differs and what's involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** spaying during heat is more dangerous and the vet charged you more because that makes the operation longer and more complex, but it's still the same operation.

**Long answer:**

Spaying is an operation where the vet has to access the internal sex organs and remove the ovaries, fallopian tubes, and often the uterus as well (source: [PetMD](https://www.petmd.com/dog/care/spay-and-neutering-dogs-101-everything-you-need-know)). However, during heat the body is fully prepared to be impregnated and care for a fetus, so these organs are supplied with much more blood than before a heat.

> The spay surgery [...] is one of the most difficult surgeries your veterinarian will perform. (source: [YourVetOnline](https://www.yourvetonline.com/can-spay-dog-heat/))

This surplus blood flow poses an additional risk for the operation. Vets have to be more careful when spaying a dog in heat and work slower. The tissue of the uterus is already bleeding on its own, but all the surrounding tissue is also more fragile and bleedings are more common. Organs are hard to make out in any situation, but the blood conceals the operation field even more. The sutures may pull through the fragile tissue and cause more internal bleeding.  An existing condition like anaemia or being overweight can quickly risk the life of the dog.

Depending on the skills and experience of the vet, many refuse to spay animals in heat. Those who do offer the operation are (usually) more experienced and usually charge more.

All that means that the recovery time for the dog may also be longer or that there may be more complications. If possible at all, you should reschedule the spaying to approx. 2 weeks later, when the heat is over.

Comment: When you say "more dangerous", by what degree? Our pup has suspected pyometra and is going to have the spay during heat on Tuesday. I've been told it's very routine.

Comment: @gator That is a question I cannot answer. It's best to discuss any concerns you have with your vet.